# Critical alert android equivalent

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I am developing an app for a local fire department using React-Native, one feature is to alert everyone in case of emergency.
On iOS I can use "Critical Alerts" which work perfectly, but I can't find a good solution for Android to bypass the mute on the phone with a push notification.
Right now I can only bypass DnD, but no sound is played.
Is there anything equivalent to "Critical alerts" for Android?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What about [notification channels](https://companion.home-assistant.io/docs/notifications/critical-notifications/)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Also, how did you manage to bypass Do not Disturb (DnD)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a working solution.
Notification channels did not work reliably, on some devices it worked, on others it did not.